# First dropdown menu not closing after hovering second menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I get some issue when opening the menu1 dropdown and directly after mouseover the menu2 to open it without closing de menu1.
If I open the menu1 and move the cursor out from the nav to close the dropdown and then mouseover the menu2 it works fine.
If I go directly from menu1 to menu2 or inversely, the menu2 dropdown appear under the menu1 dropdown. 
I thinks that I have a mistake in my html or it can be fix with a jquery function but I don't know how to solve this. I wish to add more menu, in the actually there are only two.
I hope that you understand my problem,
Any help would be appreciated

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var menu = $('.menu')
     menu.hide();
     $("#mainbutton").mouseenter(function(){
       $(".menu").stop().slideDown("fast");
     });
     $("#nav").mouseleave(function(){
       $(".menu").stop().slideUp("fast");
     });

     var menu2 = $('.menu2')
     menu2.hide();
     $("#secondboutton").mouseenter(function(){
       $(".menu2").stop().slideDown("fast");
     });
     $("#nav").mouseleave(function(){
       $(".menu2").stop().slideUp("fast");
     });
});
```

[**Here the JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/osnojofw/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to add a general class name to all menus `.menu` and a specific selector for each individual menu (`#menu1` or `.menu1`) as well as an indicator for the active state `.active`. this way you can simply close all `.menu.active`

see the following fiddle as a simple proof of concept: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ad3a5qyw/2/

EDIT:
I've abstracted the fiddle so you can add `data-menu` attributes to the `nav-items` to indicate the associated menu.

Comment: Its perfect like that, thanks you very , I really appreciate :)

Comment: @colapsnux perfect! please mark this question as answered if everything looks fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I see what's going on here:

It's easy with jQuery and the code you've written already, and here's an example with a new menu item to show how easy it is: https://jsfiddle.net/xyqoj24m/2/

What's going on is that the `mouseleave` functions are only run when the mouse leaves the *entire* `#nav` element.  So what needs to be done is handle the hiding/showing of the menus like so:

1. When the mouse hovers over a menu item, close all other dropdowns and show the correct one.
2. When the mouse leaves the dropdown or the menu item, close the dropdown.

Take a look at this **Javascript** and see what that means:

```
  $("#mainbutton").mouseenter(function(){
      $(".menu").stop().slideDown("fast"); 
      $(".menu2").stop().slideUp("fast"); 
      $(".menu3").stop().slideUp("fast");
  });

  $("#secondbutton").mouseenter(function(){
      $(".menu2").stop().slideDown("fast");  
      $(".menu").stop().slideUp("fast"); 
      $(".menu3").stop().slideUp("fast");
  });

  // leave the first menu dropdown
  $("#mainbutton, .menu").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".menu").stop().slideUp("fast");
  });

  // leave the second menu dropdown
  $("#secondbutton, .menu2").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".menu2").stop().slideUp("fast");
  });
```

Feel free to ask questions!

Comment: Thanks you very much, but it appear that when I move the cursor under the dropdown, the slideUp happen and the menu close. But the top level menu switching are nice, maybe you could fix it ? thanks you again
[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xyqoj24m/2/)